# Inverted Polygon in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, symbology, masking

Back when I used QGIS, I symbolized with the 'Inverted Polygon' setting all the time. Mostly it was to create a half-opaque mask around a feature that I wanted to pop out more prominently, but I can't figure out how to do anything similar in ArcGIS Pro.

Any tips?

Comment: I used to do them in ArcMap much the same way as described in the linked thread in PolyGeo's answer - create a global polygon (or large enough to more than cover my required extent) and then create a donut-hole over my AOI

Answer (score 3):

This appears to represent a current ArcGIS Pro limitation because there is an ArcGIS Pro Idea named [ArcGIS Pro Fill Layer Effect - Invert](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-ideas/arcgis-pro-fill-layer-effect-invert/idi-p/933242) which says:

> There is a QGIS tool called inverted polygon which does what you're
> describing, but nothing I've been able to find in Arcpro [sic]

Answer (score 0):

Generate a Euclidean Distance raster around your polygons for some distance that suits your needs.    Symbolize the resulting reclassification as desired.  You may need to take additional steps to mask out the interior of you polygon if and only if you do not want to fill the polygon with color.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar to the Euclidean Distance suggest by GBG using a gradient stroke.[image]

John Nelson has a video on youtube [Easy Vignette Effect for Your ArcGIS Online and Pro Maps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PuYOzi8zuXs) showing how to use blend modes and a global polygon to mask around features.